# GeocoderServiceError Geopy Nominatim in Local Server

Tags: python, server, local, geopy, nominatim

I did my own OpenStreetMap local server(to avoid the online limits) with Nominatim and it's working ok through the webpage(localhost/nominatim). But when I try to collect geocodes (same that works well on the webpage) and after some number of requests the server shows this error:

```
GeocoderServiceError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

I tried to put timeout in my code, but I am still facing the same problem.

My actual code is more or less like this:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
nom = Nominatim(domain='192.168.1.214/nominatim', scheme='http', timeout=3)
df1["Coordinates"]=df1["location"].apply(nom.geocode)
```

Someone know how to solve this?

Thanks ;)

Comment: Doing some tests I realized that the problem is with my server, not with my script. After doing a clean installation (as in the manual) of Nominatim, how can I remove the limitations of queries of my local server? There is any configuration file?

Comment: Folks, I solved the problem. For some reason, if you address is a very big phrase the system crash. I cleaned the dataset first, run the script again and works well.